# Initialize optim and saving model when using DataParallel

Tags: pytorch

Are the two marked lines `1)` and `2)` equivalent when using DataParallel?

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net).cuda()
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr)        # 1)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.module.parameters(), lr) # 2)
```

Or does one of them create weird synchronization issues?

Also, while saving params to file, which one is preferred when using a DataParallel module?

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(net).cuda()
...
torch.save({
  'epoch': epoch,
  'state_dict': model.state_dict(),        # 1)
  'state_dict': model.module.state_dict(), # 2)
  'best_loss': best_loss,
}, filename)
```